# How to capture stdout/stdmsg for each ansible playbook tasks with using callbacks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there any way to capture stdout,stderr on completion of each ansible playbook tasks (not the entire playbook) with using callbacks ?

Predefined "playbook_on_task_start" not meeting to actual requirement, so there need to be a provision to get stats for each individual task completion on entire playbook execution.

```
 def playbook_on_task_start(self, name, is_conditional):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach here is to create a hash of tasks when they start, and populate hash with data when task ends.
When playbook is done, you can analyze your hash and print what you need.

See [profile_tasks.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py) to get the idea of global `stats` hash and storing tasks by uuid.
You need to add `v2_runner_on_...` handlers to fetch `stdout` from result and put it into `self.stats[result._task._uuid].stdout`.
Then calculate your stats in `v2_playbook_on_stats`.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to know is there any callback for completion each individual task in playbook.

Comment: You can inspect all available callbacks [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py). As I said, you need to define `v2_runner_on_...` callbacks, e.g. `v2_runner_on_ok` for successful task completion; `v2_runner_on_failed` for failed task, etc. Also there are callbacks for looped tasks `v2_runner_item_on...`.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin!